# PublishAsync publishes multiple notifications

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I am using ABP's PublishAsync method for publishing notifications, but in some cases (in production) it creates multiple notifications instead of one. Method isn't in any loop, but still it creates multiple records in AbpTenantNotifications table (in space of 0.1 sec). Method looks like this:

```
public async Task Publish_RegularNotification(NotificationDetails notificationDetails, UserIdentifier[] users)
        {
            notificationDetails = AttachAdditionalDataToNotification(notificationDetails);

            await _notificationPublisher.PublishAsync(
                   notificationDetails.NotificationName,
                   notificationDetails,
                   severity: NotificationSeverity.Info,
                   userIds: users
                );
        }
```

Has anyone encountered this problem?

Comment: Did you pass duplicate `users`?

Comment: I did accidentally...but shouldn't that add extra row just in AbpUserNotifications and not in AbpTenantNotifications table?

Comment: Did that solve your problem?

Comment: Unfortunately not...I also subscribe some users to this entity after I send the general notification. Could this be the problem?

Comment: General notification?

Comment: Yeah scenario is like this...I have leave requests module, and when user creates leave request general notification is sent to users who have permission to approve it. Then I subscribe creator and users with permission to approve to this leave request because I have comments connected with leave requests. So if anyone comments on leave request entity notification is created and subscribed users are notified.

Comment: Please show code.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/dkisic/804f5ae79754f328cb97dda11f2e3724

Comment: Seems fine. Please create a repro project on GitHub that is forked from [aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template).